# Separating data in Redis

Tags: redis, database, nosql

I am currently working on an application that uses Redis. The app lists a bunch of data like this:

```
First name: Peter
Last name: Gabriel
Occupation: Singer
```

We are using Redis to store some information about the fields (visible/hidden, sort order, display name etc...).

The data is stored as hashes in Redis like this:

```
firstname
    display
        true
    order
        1
    editable
        false

lastname
    display
        true
    order
        2
    editable
        false

occupation
    display
        true
    order
        3
    editable
        true
```

All of this data is stored in database '0'.

Now, we want our users to be able to submit change requests on the value. We want to use Redis to store the list of change requests as well:

```
bradpitt
    maritalstatus
        [{ old: 'married', new: 'divorced' }]
```

Seeing as this is data meant to be used for two different cases, is there some way to logically separate data in Redis. In MongoDB, you have collections, in SQL you have tables. Are there any Redis equivalent, or should I just put it in the same place? Should I use database '1'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In redis world, there are many data structures, but they are all stored by key-value. There are no thing in redis like table or collections.

You should carefully name all the keys, and save all keys string in a file (e.g. common/constants). For example , if you want to store users info by hash in redis, you can do this:

```
USER_INFO_HASH_KEY = "user_info_%s"
```

In other places of your app code, you can import this key from common/constants and use the user_id to fill the placeholder and get the real key. like this :

```
key = USER_INFO_HASH_KEY % user_id 
redis_conn.hset(key, field, value)
```

By this methods, you can manage all the keys of redis in your application by a constants file, and not worry about key name conflicts.

Also you should choose different db to store your different data, because maybe there are many cases in you app development and operation, maybe you want to flush some data, if you store very import data in a db, and cheap data in other db, you can easily do this thing. But it depends on you.